# Remove the last extension from path

Tags: powershell

By using **(get-command Oscdimg).Path** , I able to retrieve the full path.

Here is what I get : **D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe**

What I want actually : **D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg**

I don't want the oscdimg.exe inside my path. Is there any method to remove it?

Comment: do you mean Get-ChildItem?  In that case you could do $DirectoryName = (Get-ChildItem 'D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe').DirectoryName

Comment: @phiz Yes it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the @phiz comment

```
$filename = "D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe"
$file = Get-ChildItem $filename
$file.DirectoryName
```

**Output**

```
D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a cmdlet for doing just what you ask. [*grin*] lookee ...

```
$FilePath = 'D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe'

Split-Path -Path $FilePath -Parent
```

output ...

```
D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "replace" operator ?
Ex.
Input :

```
'D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg.exe' -replace '.exe',''
```

Output :

```
'D:\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Deployment Tools\amd64\Oscdimg\oscdimg'
```

Comment: Hmm what I want is totally remove the oscdimg.exe from me path. Not only the .exe word. But I got the answer, you can refer from above. Thanks.